# How to typeset a critical apparatus like the commented "Mein Kampf" edition?

Tags: books, critical

I happen to own the commented edition of "Mein Kampf", where there are lots of comments on historical events, lies he told for propaganda etc.

It looks like this:

[image]

Right now, I'm working on a document and my task is to create a critical apparatus for it.

The Hitler-book does it like this:

You have the original text on the right and comments about changes through time on the right margin. The whole left page is just comments about stuff on the right page. The interesting part is that the comment starts at the same (x, y)-position as the text commented (marked in text by e.g. "#").

Is there anything similiar I can do in LaTeX? I'm looking for a command like

```
original text before notated text, \annotate{original text}{my comment} original text after notated text,
```

so that on the left (or right) page (e.g. the page before the text or after it) my comment appears on the same (x, y)-coordinates as on "original text" has on the other page.

Something like "todonotes", but more complex to do, surely, but way better looking and readable.

Comment: I think the standard package for producing critical editions is `reledmac`. It probably won't get you the exact formatting, but given the complexity of the job, it should go a long way to getting something just as usable.

Comment: For complexity, you need flowfram.  (With great power comes lots of detail work.)

Answer (score 1):

As Alan Munn mentions in a comment, the most comprehensive solution to this would probably be [reledmac](https://ctan.org/pkg/reledmac) (which is the latest iteration of a long-established sequence of packages specifically aimed at producing critical editions).

A more lightweight solution, which addresses your main question – producing text on an opposite page, keyed to the position on the recto page – is my [versonotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/versonotes) package, which aims to do exactly that, and no more.

Which package is most appropriate depends on exactly how much you want to achieve.